# Import png files and save as subplots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to import two png files and stich them into subplots using matplotlib. I am following this [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) to do this. But when I save the figure with a 2x2 subplot, the resolution is very poor. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you show us _excactly_ how you are saving the figures?  I suspect the problem is that the default dpi is too low for your purposes.

Comment: @tcaswell, I was just using `fig.savefig('test.png')` without specifying `dpi`. I will give that a try, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the resolution is satisfactory before you save, try using the `dpi` keyword along with `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()` (see docs page for [matplotlib.pyplot.savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)).  Once you have the plot generated, simply type

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import savefig
savefig( 'stitched.png', dpi=400 )
```

and hopefully this results in a satisfactory png.